# Double integral were y is negative and positive

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to evaluate: $\int\int xydA$

Where D is the region bounded by the line $y=x-2$ and $x=y^2$

[image]

Does the integral need to be set up as:

$$\int_{-1}^{2} \int_{y+2}^{y^2} xydxdy$$

or do I need to evaluate the double integral of the area above the y-axis and below separately and add them together like this?

$$\int_{-1}^{0} \int_{x-2}^{\sqrt x} xydydx + \int_{0}^{2} \int_{x-2}^{\sqrt x} xydydx$$

Or am I completely wrong and it's something totally different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two integrals are the same. In this case you do not need to break it up (though you're welcome to if you want to). In some integrals you *have to* break it up because the bounds change. If your bounding functions cross, or if you have several functions bounding a shape and which one is bounding the slice you are looking at changes, then you have to break it up because the integrals *can't* combine the way these two can.

Comment: OK my first integral is correct? I just want to make sure that I am understanding this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yup! You're good.